# Find out if a specific fragment is currently shown

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to handle an "`onBackPressed`" event and want to check the currently viewed fragment

So it's simply like when you press the "back" button I want my App to check if `fragment_main` is shown
If it is, close the app
If not get back to it.

Can I do this by using a Fragment Manager?
I didn't find helpful examples on the internet...

Here is my code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.app.FragmentManager;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


        Fragment Main = (Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.MainFrag);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem!

Now I created a new activity which is called by an `Intent` and android automatically handles the `onBackPressed()` event.
But thanks for your help!

Comment: This is perfectly fine, but it works the same way with fragments. They also get pushed on the backstack and are handled the same way as activities on onBackPressed...

Answer (score 0):

Check out Fragment.getUserVisibleHint(). This should tell you if the fragment is currently visible.

Comment: I'm just thinking about whats better:

Comment: Using Fragments and switch their visibilities/Show the main Fragment when the back button is pressed
Or creating a new activity for each site.

Whats better if I want to create abour 20 Sites you can show by clicking buttons?